# How do I use flows to update a custom picklist/text field everytime a topic is added to a contact or lead?

Tags: apex, lightning, visual-flows, topics, config

Ideal outcome: When we select an interest tag for a contact or lead record, the flows automations would automatically populate the corresponding interest tags values on a custom field (whether it be a text field or multi-picklist field).

Currently I am having difficulties organising the flows for it to work. I am using 'Topic Assignment' as the object when triggered as Topics are directly linked with the interest tags being chosen.

Any help would be appreciated, thank you!

Comment: The Topic Assignment is definitely the right object to trigger this automation, so that's a great start. To truly help with your question though, it would be great to understand what you've done so far and what exactly you're having difficulty with. I've got an approach in mind but keen to understand exactly what you are struggling with before I answer.

Comment: Hey @CallumMacErlich thanks for your response. I plan to approach it like this:
Set up a flow that starts when a Topic Assignment record changes.
Find all Topic Assignment records connected to the same Contact or Lead.
Create a loop to go through these Topic Assignments one by one.
In each loop, collect the name of the Topic into a text string, separating each with a semi-colon.
Once all Topic Assignments have been checked, update the Contact or Lead's custom field with the string of Topic names.
Save and activate the flow to make it live.

Hope this makes things clearer